# ROS node implementation

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to implement C# in ROS, and I want to first initialize a C# node.

I found the code in roslib, /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/xmlrpc.py, seems to have implemented node(by class XmlRpcNode(object)).But I am not sure if this file is the right one I am looking for.

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12095/ros-node-implementation/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Implementing a ROS client library in C# is not trivial. Some information on the client protocol can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview). What you essentially need to do is:

- Implement the [slave API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Slave_API) which is based on XMLRPC.
- Implement a message generator that parses [msg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg) files and generates C# code for serialization an deserialization
- Implement the [TCPROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/TCPROS) transport.

Also have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Implementing%20Client%20Libraries) wiki page and [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/10399/is-ros-able-to-support-c-language) question.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3